# Plug vs Socket: Interchangeable?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, definiciones, modismos

Many dictionaries that I have looked at online seem to use `enchufe` as a word that is interchangeable for the English words `plug` and `socket`, which are two related, but distinct objects.  Some dictionaries list `toma de corriente` as an alternative, but my personal experience has simply been `enchufe`.  Am I wrong?  In which contexts would I use `enchufe` vs. `toma de corriente`?

Comment: +1 Good question!

Answer (score 7):

Toma de corriente (or [Tomacorriente](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=tomacorriente)):

[image]

Enchufe:

[image]

I wouldn't say they are interchangeable at all. They are clearly different things.

**EDIT**

As Javi and Dusan have said, enchufe is used sometimes to refer to a tomacorriente. I've definitely heard people using it in the way Juanillo mentions:

> ¿Dónde hay un enchufe para conectar el portátil?

[RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=enchufe) has this definition for enchufe:

> Dispositivo formado por dos piezas que se encajan una en otra cuando se quiere establecer una conexión eléctrica.

That definition seems to indicate that an `enchufe` is really formed by both devices, the plug and the socket; but again, enchufe is used to refer to a socket as well.

I still prefer to differentiate between them by calling enchufe to the plug and tomacorriente to the socket. For example, Juanillo's example could be expressed as:

> ¿En dónde hay un tomacorriente para conectar mi portátil?

Comment: At least in Spain, both can be called as enchufe. "Toma de corriente" is a more a technical name and non-technician people use "enchufe". As "¿dónde hay un enchufe para conectar el portátil?"

Comment: In Chile also both are called 'enchufe'.

Comment: You call both `enchufe`? So you say: `Conecta el enchufe en el enchufe`?

Comment: @César people tend to make things as short as possible so they would just say "conecta el enchufe" (it's obvious where) or just "enchúfalo". One of them is "enchufe macho" and the other is "enchufe hembra", but people uses just enchufe because most of the time it's understood by the context which one is. http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchufe

Comment: @Javi thanks I get it now, I was thinking something else because you can connect an `enchufe` in a `supresor de picos` for example.

Comment: @Javi, Dusan, you guys are correct. I've heard people using enchufe to refer to a toma corriente. I will amend my answer.